# CSV migration always returns "id is defined as a source ID but has no value"

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a freshly composer installed Drupal 8.6.13. I tried to migrate csv sources and allways got the error message

> [error] Migration failed with source plugin exception: id is defined as a source ID but has no value.

I switched to an example that is running in another installation https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source-plugins/migrating-data-from-a-csv-source, but still get this error.

My versions: migrate  8.6.13, migrate_plus 8.x-4.1, migrate_source_csv 8.x-2.2, migrate_tools 8.x-4.1

Does anyone have an idea what causes the error?

This are the files:

CSV:

```
id,title,body 
1,title 1,some body text 1 
2,title 2,some body text 2 
3,title 3,some body text 3
```

Migration configuration:

```
id: article_csv_import
label: Import articles
migration_groups:
  - ACME import
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: 'public://articles.csv'
  delimiter: ','
  enclosure: '"'
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - id
  column_names:
    0:
      id: 'Unique Id'
    1:
      title: 'Title'
    2:
      body: 'Post body'
process:
  title: title
  body: body
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article

destination:
  plugin: entity:node
```

Answer (score -1):

I already had the same error you've got; in fact it's a mistake :
Please double check that the delimiter set in the yml file is the same as in your source file (edit it with notepad++ to be sure). Sometimes Excel change delimiter when reopening csv file before resave it without settings file format.

Also, note the `column_names` key is not mandatory, as the plugin will automagically extract column from your file (see `migrate_source_csv\src\Plugin\migrate\source\CSV.php` line 110 ... 123). Here you can also print the `$column_names` array to check if it contains same number of items as your file columns.

BR